Media3 ExoPlayer Not Playing FLV, ASF, or MPEG Formats: What Are the Solutions?
I'm currently working on an Android app using Media3 ExoPlayer, and I'm facing issues with playing media files in FLV, ASF, and MPEG formats. I’ve tried loading these files, but ExoPlayer seems to lack support for these formats.
Are there any workarounds to play FLV and ASF formats directly in ExoPlayer?
Should I consider using any external libraries for this purpose?
Are there specific settings or configurations in ExoPlayer that could help?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Checked the documentation for supported formats.
Tried converting the files to MP4, which works fine. But it take to much time for long duration videos so I skip this.
Verified that the permissions for accessing local storage are correctly set.
I would like to know:

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I encountered the same issue and resolved it by using the nextlib from https://github.com/anilbeesetti/nextlib. I set the render factory provided by the library to address the problem.

Use FFMPEG Extension with ExoPlayer

FFMPEG can support FLV and ASF

Here is the dependency:
implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-ffmpeg:1.0.0'

Ensure that the extension is initialized and configured to handle formats that ExoPlayer doesn’t natively support.
Activity or Fragment code:
val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
.setRenderersFactory(DefaultRenderersFactory(context).setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_ON))
.build()

If the issue not resolved, then you can consider third party libraries like VLC or IjkPlayer

we are tried this method but its not working

then consider third party libraries like VLC or IjkPlayer
